# PHPMailer failing

Tags: php, phpmailer

Ok, I'm guessing this is something simple or I'm using something deprecated that I didn't know about.

I'll remove superfluous bits from my code, but everything removed has been tested.

The original code is based on a very common tutorial script that I've seen everywhere. It is getting to the line:

```
while ($row = $res->fetch_array()) {
```

and the php is failing with a common: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object.

Normally this would flag to me that my SQL is failing or returning something unwanted, I'd have a minor fix and then move on with my life. However that doesn't appear to be the case. I've been over and over that SQL and it is returning what I want it to.

I thought it might have something to do with calling the while loop inside the else (but that shouldn't be a problem) or that the mail call is within the while loop.

Original Code:

```
$email = $link->real_escape_string($_POST["web_forgot_email"]);
$sendemail = 0; 

$sql = "SQL to return Name and Email (Tested extensively and works)";
$res = $link->query($sql);

if ($res->num_rows == 0) {
    $arr = array("web_forgot_success" => "web no account");
    echo json_encode($arr);
} else {    
    while ($row = $res->fetch_array()) {
        $sendemail = $row['CLIENT_EMAIL'];
        $name = $row['NAME'];

        require("class.phpmailer.php");
        $mail = new PHPMailer();    
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->Host = "localhost";
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = "quizzically@quizzically.co.uk"; 
        $mail->Password = "quizzically01";                  
        $mail->From = "quizzically@quizzically.co.uk";
        $mail->FromName = "quizzically";
        $mail->AddAddress($sendemail);
        $mail->WordWrap = 50;
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = "quizzically password reset confirmation";
        $mailer = "Email Message";
        $mail->Body = $mailer;
        if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $arr = array("web_forgot_success" => "web no send");
        echo json_encode($arr);
        } else {
        $arr = array("web_forgot_success" => "web forgot success");
        echo json_encode($arr);
        }
    }
}
```

So I rejigged code so that it finds variables $sendemail and $name first and then send an email but every time (even though the $sendemail variable is not 0) it skips that if statement and returns the else. I've tested the $sendemail variable by sending it back to myself in the else variable and it is definitely not 0.

Good thing is that the PHP does not fail, bad thing is that something is causing the code to skip the whole if section dealing with sending the email.

Rejigged Code:

```
$email = $link->real_escape_string($_POST["web_forgot_email"]);
$sendemail = 0; 

$sql = "SQL to return Name and Email (Tested extensively and works)";
$res = $link->query($sql);

if ($res->num_rows == 0) {
    $arr = array("web_forgot_success" => "web no account");
    echo json_encode($arr);
} 

while ($row = $res->fetch_array()) {
    $sendemail = $row['CLIENT_EMAIL'];
    $name = $row['NAME'];
}

if ($sendemail != 0) {
    require("class.phpmailer.php");    
    $mail = new PHPMailer();    
    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->Host = "localhost"; 
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
    $mail->Username = "quizzically@quizzically.co.uk"; 
    $mail->Password = "quizzically01";              
    $mail->From = "quizzically@quizzically.co.uk";
    $mail->FromName = "quizzically";
    $mail->AddAddress($sendemail);
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = "quizzically password reset confirmation";     
    $mailer = "Email Message";
    $mail->Body = $mailer;

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $arr = array("web_forgot_success" => "web no send");
        echo json_encode($arr);
    } else {
        $arr = array("web_forgot_success" => "web forgot success");
        echo json_encode($arr);
    }
} else {
    $arr = array("web_forgot_success" => "web forgot failed");
    echo json_encode($arr);
}
```

I'm hoping that I'm doing something deprecated that I haven't found or whatnot, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in my own inability to test fully. I had an issue with the html in the message of the email I was sending. This must have been throwing up and error and then the PHP failed on the while loop.

Error in the HTML fixed (it was an un-escaped double quote) and everything is sending fine with no errors.